# Django 1.6 Block Trans not working with variable

Tags: python, django, internationalization, translation

I am trying to translate a paragraph of text with a block trans tag like the following:

```
{% url 'mymodel.view.results' result_id as results_url %}
{% blocktrans %}See your results here: <a href='{{results_url}}'>Results</a>{% endblocktrans %}
```

The text in the block trans is not being translated even though all the text around it is being translated.  The translations are not marked as fuzzy and in the .po file the text looks like this:

```
#: templates/results.html:10
4
#, python-format
msgid ""
"See your results here: "
"<a href='%(results_url)s'>Results</a>"
msgstr ""
"Para su conveniencia <a "
"href='%(results_url)s'>Resultados </a>"
```

Is there anything that is wrong with the way the translations show up?  I notice that it shows %()s instead of {{}} in the block trans.  But I'm assuming that is the way django marks it as a variable in the po file.  What can I do to make it so that translations work for block trans with a variable in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must pass variables into `blocktrans` to use them inside. Without that django can't translate this sentence, because when rendered it looks like this:

```
sentence = _('See your results here: <a href='%(results_url)s'>Results</a>" % {'results_url': results_url})
```

In other words, each time template is rendered, translation engine is getting string with results_url already populated.

You must make it equivalent to that code:

```
sentence = _('See your results here: <a href='%(results_url)s'>Results</a>") % {'results_url': results_url}
```

and to do that, simply pass your variable into blocktrans:

```
{% blocktrans with results_url=results_url %}See your results here: <a href='{{results_url}}'>Results</a>{% endblocktrans %}
```